Ubuntu upgraded to 24.04 from 22.10, now getting grub message "Symbol ‘grub disk native sectors’ not found"
I have seen several questions about the same issue but they are either not answered or the answer is not relevant as it is about a different Linux variant
When performing the upgrade, towards the end of the process, I kept getting a message about something not responding and waited 5 or 6 times before I thought it best to force it to stop. After the restart I got the message in the title.
I have downloaded the boot repair disk and run it several times but it didn't work. I generated a report on pastebin at https://paste.ubuntu.com/pRD5n4vPvp
This is an old system with MBR/msdos partitions on the boot disk.
I don't have a USB stick of more than 4GB that I can use and I also can burn an ISO on my windows system if I need to - but 24.04 iso is about 6GB.

Pastebin does not exist. If older system that is BIOS/MBR probably better to use lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
I use Kubuntu which is somewhat lighter on both newer & older systems. And its ISO is under 4GB.

Thanks for the information about the ubuntu flavours. I may try doing a re-install but I have an old mysql installation that I wanted to try to get working again as it seemed to get corrupted a while back and I didn't have time to try to sort it then but would like to now and want to avoid over-writing it with a new O/S install. I;ve tried creating a new pastebin but it still didn't work even though I was really careful copying it. down.

I encountered this problem after a release upgrade from 22.04 LTS (Jammy) to 24.04 LTS (Noble).
Problem
Booting causes the machine to hang in grub showing
error: symbol 'grub_disk_native_sectors' not found.

Attempts to fix this within grub are not successful and just cause a different message:
error: symbol 'grub_register_command_lockdown' not found.

Solution

Download Ubuntu ISO image.

I used the 22.04 Live Server image (2 GB).
It might also work with 24.04 Live Server image (2.6 GB), I didn't try.


Flash the image using Rufus 3.14 or newer to an USB medium. Do not use an older version.

Boot from USB.

Answer the questions to select your language and keyboard settings.

Open a shell by pressing Ctrl + Alt + 2

Find your root partition. This is a common setup:

Disk is /dev/sda
Boot partition is /dev/sda1
Root partition is /dev/sda2.


chroot into your root partition (e.g. /dev/sda2):
 ubuntu-server@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo su
 root@ubuntu-server:/home/ubuntu-server# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
 root@ubuntu-server:/home/ubuntu-server# for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do mount --bind "${dir}" "/mnt${dir}"; done
 root@ubuntu-server:/home/ubuntu-server# chroot /mnt /bin/bash


Update the bootloader of your disk (e.g. /dev/sda):
 root@ubuntu-server:/# grub-install /dev/sda
 root@ubuntu-server:/# update-grub


Reboot


